# Convert a structure of date and time to time only in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this form date and time like :

```
2021-06-04 11:23:37.000
```

i am trying to convert this form to time only :

after change:

```
11:23:37
```

Note this form `2021-06-04 11:23:37.000` is fix.

Comment: `'2021-06-04 11:23:37.000'.substr(11, 8)`

Comment: that it , thank you

Comment: Try `new Date('2021-06-04 11:23:37.000').toLocaleTimeString('en-GB')`

Answer (score 2):

You can just split it on the basis of   (space), and access the element at index `1` which would be time.

```js
let d = "2021-06-04 11:23:37.000"

console.log(d.split(" ")[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```js
console.log("2021-06-04 11:23:37.000".match(/\d+:\d+:\d+/))
```

Basically, we use regex to find digits (`\d+`) followed by a colon (`:`), followed by digits (`\d+`) followed by a colon (`:`), followed by the last digits (`\d+`) - and this ensures that the period won't be captured.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the available [date methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to format the date to your needs.

```js
const date = new Date('2021-06-04 11:23:37.000');

const result = `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `2021-06-04 11:23:37.000` is a non-standard date format and should not be used with `Date(string)` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `#substring()`:

```
var date = '2021-06-04 11:23:37.000';
console.log(date.substring(11));
```

PS: `#substr()` is obsolete